# Repositioning Genesis Nav not working - Issue with remove_action()

Tags: wordpress, menu, themes, nav, genesis

I'm new to Genesis (and stack overflow).

I used the following code to reposition my primary and secondary navs above my header, which worked, however it also left a copy of both navs below the header in it's original place. So basically duplicated my navs :(

```js
// Reposition the primary navigation menu
remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_nav', 12 );

// Reposition the secondary navigation menu
remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_subnav' );
add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'genesis_do_subnav' );
```

Any ideas? The test site I'm playing around with is at: http://atelierblanc.pixelboutique.co.uk

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove_action() must be called inside a function and cannot be called directly in your plugin or theme.

you may try this :

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_my_action' );
function remove_my_action(){
    remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
    remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_subnav' );
}
```

you can learn more here :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action